# In Java, defining an array allocates space for references or for the objects themselves?

Tags: java, arrays, memory, reference

In the following line of code, does the compiler allocate memory to store 10 objects of MyClass or 10 references?

```
MyClass[] arr= new MyClass[10];
```

In other words, do arrays store references alone or the objects themselves?

Also, is the behaviour different for primitive types?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

It allocates space for the references. In case of primitive types it allocates space = array length * primitive type byte size.

Answer (score 5):

When created like this, arrays are automatically initialized with the default value of their type, so `arr` gets initialized with 10 `null` references.